# How to disable net.simonvt.menudrawer to right in android

Tags: android, android-activity

I am using net.simonvt.menudrawer(3rd party lib) for Menu drawer.How to disable right swipe in android

and please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after some r&d got some solution but i am thinking this is not the perfect sol. finally changing the right menu drawer size to Zero as 
MenuDrawer.setMenuSize(0);